# Rails CSS for text_field_tag default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Text field Tag:

```
<%= text_field_tag :note, "#{f.notes}", :placeholder => 'Add a note about this rating set..' %>
```

How can I style `f.notes` to have a background color so that the note looks highlighted after being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

if you put

```
:class => 'cssclass'
```

it will add the css class style that you want

Comment: This add a background color to the entire filed. I just want the color to be applied to the `f.notes` default value.

Comment: did you do font color? or just color

Comment: I used `background-color`.

Comment: Conditionally add the class. Add "notes-default" class when it's at it's default value, and don't add it when it's not it's default value.